# Best way to get from SeaTac airport to Redmond?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, taxis, sea

Can anyone suggest the best way to get from Seattle-Tacoma (SEA) airport up to Redmond?

I guess one option might be the new tram into the center of Seattle, then try to change onto one of the Express buses out to Redmond (e.g. the 545), assuming you don't have to walk too far to change? Or are you better off trying to stick with buses the whole way?

I'm not keen on the idea of hiring a car to do it, but if a taxi could do it for a sensible price then I might not be averse...!

Comment: I suggest being an ex-Microsoft employee, having lots of friends who still live in the area, and calling one of them up to give you a ride. Better yet, simply post on Facebook or LinkedIn that you'll be traveling there soon, and see which one volunteers to pick you up first...

Comment: To those voting down, please explain why with a comment!

Comment: Not a down-vote but a tip: "best" works better if you state what criteria are important to you: price, speed, convenience, easy with luggage, rain avoidance, etc.  "Best" really depends on your specific priorities, preferences and constraints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually plan my trips with Google Maps. Put both address and click on the public transportation. In your case: http://goo.gl/maps/O1f7
This is a 2 hour travel time for 27 miles and about US$5.00 price (two fares if you get bus and train). Notice that you can get the train from the airport parking directly instead of picking up a bus first.
You may think about US$74.00 for a taxi from this site:
http://www.worldtaximeter.com/seattle/sea+tac+airport/redmond

Comment: Just checked my last expense report and the cab was $60 with tip. I never land at rush hour though, which will obviously cost more.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised that Google Maps covered public transport in Seattle. Will give it a whirl shortly!

Answer (score 12):

Redmond is a crappy place to be without a car of any sort. The only reasonable mass transit around there is an infrequent bus system designed mostly to get employees to and from Microsoft. It can take 2 hours via public transit. Taxis are not cruising the streets so you have to call them well in advance, even from major locations like the Microsoft campus.

Under most circumstances your best bet is to rent a car. Seattle airport has convenient car rental directly outside the airport (no need to take a "car rental shuttle"). I have made it to Redmond within 45 minutes of stepping off a plane, even including the time to rent a car.

If you absolutely don't want to drive yourself, you can take a private taxi, although once you get to Redmond, you'll be pretty much stuck wherever the taxi drops you because things are very, very far apart. There's also a shared-van service called SuperShuttle which is cheaper than a taxi but which will drop off a half dozen people at different locations so it takes longer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/SeaTac-Airport/Redmond) you have 2 options for public transport, which
 will take you between 1h12 and 1h28